# SocketIO ReactJS - socket.io doesn't displays console.log()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm working on SocketIO with ReactJS vie a chat app.

When emitting message to my server my client doesn't receive the response of my server. The `console.log` controlling the mechanism is never displayed.

I can't figure out why since I follow exactly the SocketIO blueprint.

here my client.js :

```
 send=  (e) => {  
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const  socket=  io.connect(this.state.endpoint); 
    socket.emit("message", () => {
      message: "hey !"
    })

    console.log("send ended")
  }

  componentDidMount(){ 
    const  socket=  io.connect(this.state.endpoint); 
    socket.on("new_message", (message) => { 
      console.log("new message ", message)
    })

    socket.on("user_connected", (message) => { 
      console.log(message)
    })
  }
```

here my server.js :

```
 client.on("message", (message) => {
   client.emit("new_message", message)
  })
```

Any hint would be great,
Thanks

Comment: Just out of interest - why are you recreating a socket every time a message is sent?

Comment: Why are you trying to send an arrow function to the server? Also sidenote, to return an object (and not create a block) from an arrow function, you need parentheses: `() => ({ message: "hey!" })`

Comment: @DacreDenny : it's because my socket's connection is out my ComponentDidMount scope

Comment: @Li357 : I take note thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you essentially have multiple instances of socket connections created over the life span of your client component.

From the server's perspective, the `"new_message"` is being emitted to the socket that you created in your components `send` arrow function. Because that socket instance does not listen to `"new_message"`, you're therefore not going to see the expected log messages in the console.

Perhaps you could consider refactoring your client component code like this, to connect a single socket, and use that as a single means of sending and listening to messages from the server?

```
class YourComponent extends Component {

  // Add socket field to component class
  socket : ''

 // Note that the send method is not an arrow function here, so
 // care should be taken to consider how you invoke send() if
 // your current implementation relies on this being an arrow function
 function send(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const socket = this.state.socket // UPDATE: Access socket via state

    // Send messages to server via the same socket instance of this class
    if(socket) {

      socket.emit("message", () => {
        message: "hey !"
      })

      console.log("send ended")
    }
  }

 function componentDidMount(){ 

    const socket = io.connect(this.state.endpoint)

    socket.on("new_message", (message) => { 
      console.log("new message ", message)
    })

    socket.on("user_connected", (message) => { 
      console.log(message)
    })

    // UPDATE: Connect the socket, and hold a reference for reuse by the component class 
    // instance via the component's state (seeing you can't add a class field for this)
    this.setState({ socket : socket }) 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, I can't add the socket item in the void directly like this

Comment: can you add your socket instance to the components state, ie via this.setState() ?

Comment: I'm trying. It returns me "> cannot read property 'endpoint' of undefined"

Comment: I have basically set my socket connection out of my component with a scope on whole file, works good now I receive the message from my server